# MySQL, PHP, PDO "could not find driver" error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting the "could not find driver" error....  Any ideas?  I've stared at this for a long time so I need a fresh set of eyes on it.  Thanks!

```
<?php

    try {

    $objDb = new PDO('myql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    '$user', '$pass');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT *    
            FROM 'departments'
            WHERE 'code' = 0";
    $statement = $objDb->query($sql);
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

     }
    ?>
```

I'm at a loss....I have all of this setup at home so I have root to everything.  Here's what I know:

```
**phpinfo()**

**PDO**
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql 

**pdo_mysql**
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $ 

**mysql**
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: b0b3b15c693b7f6aeb3aa66b646fee339f175e39 $
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error string you get?

Comment: Thank you! I had just edited my post to add the code brackets, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Apart from @Explosion Pills's answer, you should not quote your table and column names with `'` in your query. You should use a backtick, but that is only necessary for column / table names that are reserved words in mysql.

Comment: I had actually fixed that as well, but didn't update that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `myql` instead of `mysql`.

```
$objDb = new PDO('myql:host=localhost;dbname=test', ...
```

`PDO` derives the driver to use from the name there, so it's looking for a `myql` driver.

Comment: omg....   Thank you!  See, I told you I needed a fresh set of eyes! :)  That fixed it.  Dang typo!